# Can Borland StarTeam 2008 Release R2 be integrated with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, starteam

I am wondering if Borland StarTeam 2008 Release R2 can be integrated with Jenkins. Or do i need to upgrade StarTeam. If yes, please let me  know where can i find the integration instructions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borland developed a StarTeam plugin for Jenkins back in 2007. Until 2013, the plugin was community-maintained, so you can find the source code in [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/starteam-plugin) and the .hpi files in [Jenkins plugins page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/StarTeam). Probably most of those versions will work seamlessly with StarTeam 2008 R2.

Since version 0.7.2, released in June 2015, they decided to rewrite the plugin and newer versions only work with StarTeam 14.4 or later.